# Just a question regarding continuous differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

$ f: [0,1] \to [0,1] $ be a MONOTONE & CONTINUOUS function. Does it always imply that: $ f(x) $ is continuously differentiable??

Comment: No. Although monotonic functions can't be too wild, they need not be differentiable. Consider $f(x) = \frac12 x - \frac13 \lvert x -\frac12\rvert$ for a trivial example.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function is a fine counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: Take, for example, $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x$ for $x < \frac{1}{2}$, and $f(x) = \frac{3}{2}x - \frac{1}{2}$ for $x \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Or any function with a corner, or something more complicated like the [Devil's Staircase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: Hmm...oh ho!! Many many thanks.... I didn't give a thought for simple linear functions....